# How do I send a message to all members with a certain role via DMs?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a report command that will DM all staff with a message due to some of them muting the server. This bot is only for my server in order to try to not to go against Discord's API. Whenever I do the command, this pops up in console:

> (node:17644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
>       at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\myname\Desktop\LDU_Bot\cmds\report.js:5:35)

Here is the code:

```
module.exports.run = async (Discord, fs, xp, bot, message, args) =>{
    var staffID = "503409681876779032";
    //console.log(`Staff: ${staff}`);
    for (let i = 0; i < message.guild.members.size; i++) {
        if (message.guild.members[i].roles.has(staff)) { //Error on this line
            message.guild.members[i].user.send(`This is a test for our report command. DM the bot dev if you are not staff.`);
        }
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "report"
}
```

The error says that the problem is at line 5 but I still don't see the problem because from what I can see, this follows the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var staffID = "503409681876779032";

message.guild.members.forEach( (member) => {
        if(member.roles.has(staffID)) {
            member.send(`This is a test for our report command. DM the bot dev if you are not staff.`); 
        }
    })
```

Comment: the i in members[i] is not defined

Comment: woops my  bad, fixed.